# Multiple faithful representation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I came across the following paragraph on pp.56 of Marshall Hall’s “The theory of groups” 1959 ed.

> ... the non-Abelian group of order 6 may be faithfully represented as a transitive permutation group on three letters and also on six letters ...

My question is,

> In general, is there a theory about this? That is, given a non-Abelian group of order n, on what conditions it can be faithfully represented by different transitive permutation groups?
>
> If the answer to the above question is yes, how do we call it? Multiple faithful representation? or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if there is a special name for this property, but I doubt it, as it is a very common property. Every finite group $G$ has a faithful transitive permutation representation on $|G|$ points, by Cayley's theorem. Given any subgroup $H$ of $G,$ there is a transitive permutation action of $G$ on the (say right) cosets of $H$ in $G$ – however, this action is not necessarily faithful. Its kernel is $\cap_{g \in G} g^{-1}Hg$, so the action is faithful just when $H$ contains no non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$. There are non-Abelian finite groups in which every proper non-trivial subgroup contains a proper non-trivial normal subgroup (such as (non-Abelian) Hamiltonian groups), but they are very much the exception, rather than the rule (to be precise, the exceptions are those non-Abelian groups in which every subgroup of prime order is normal). All other finite non-Abelian groups $G$ have a proper non-trivial subgroup $H$ such that $G$ acts faithfully and transitively on the $[G:H]$ right cosets of $H$ in $G.$

Comment: In fact, a finite group $G$ in which every subgroup of prime order is normal has to be solvable, but that requires some non-trivial group theory. Here's an outline: the derived subgroup $G^{\prime}$ has all subgroups of prime order central. This implies that for each odd prime $p$, $G^{\prime}$ has a normal $p$-complement. Thus $G^{\prime}$ has a normal Sylow $2$-subgroup, and when that is factored out, the quotient group is a nilpotent group of odd order. Thus $G^{\prime}$ is solvable, and so is $G.$

Comment: Do we have non-trivial examples other than M. Hall used? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Geoff Robinson's answer is perfect, of course, but I submit this answer to address your comment below Geoff's answer.  (I can't write this as a comment because I want to include a picture.)

As Geoff points out, there are many non-trivial examples other than the example Hall presents.  Consider the smallest non-abelian simple group, $A_5$.  It is simple -- i.e. has no non-trivial normal subgroups -- so, for the reasons given by Geoff, every (non-trivial) permutation representation is faithful.

Here is a table (excerpted from my GapNotes.pdf) of all the permutation representations of $A_5$:

[image]

By the way, my profile picture happens to be the subgroup lattice of $A_5$.  So, by looking at it, you can see the congruence lattice -- or "systems of imprimitivity," as the group theorists say -- of each of these representations; it's the interval above the given subgroup.  The picture also makes it apparent that there are three primitive representations (since there are three conjugacy classes of maximal subgroups).

Comment: Geoff Robinson's answer is direct, thus I accept it. However, I really like this answer because I have something to work with. The only thing I can say is, thanks!